# Moving average varying window

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, zoo, rolling-computation

I have an unbalanced panel, in which I have certain observations (variable x) per ID and month. I am trying to calculate a 6-month-rolling average of x, but only every March. I know that with `zoo`, I can calculate the average every single time, but I think that is computationally expensive. I have a very large panel, so it would be better to define an index first and pass it to the function. Also, my panel is imbalanced, so sometimes I have all 6 past values at a given March, and sometimes I do not. If there is a minimum of 3 values available, I would still like to compute the average.

Here is some sample code and my solution so far:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
time=rep(seq(as.Date("2010-02-01"), length=42, by="1 month") - 1,2)
IDs=rep(letters[1:2],each=length(time))
DT <- data.table(time=time,
                 ID=IDs,
                 ind=rep(1:(2*length(time))),
                 row=1:(2*length(time)),
                 x=sample(2*length(time)))
DT

DT <- DT[!ind %in% c(11,12,26)]
DT


library(zoo)
DT[,movavg := if(length(x) >= 3){ rollapply(x, 6, sum, na.rm = FALSE,align = "right",fill = NA)}else{
  rep(NA,length(x))
},by=ID]
DT
```

The target is to simply show for each March the corresponding moving average, which contains the past 6 observations. I don't mind if the original panel is kept, that is, only in March the results are shown, or if only the March values are extracted and nothing else is shown.

My code works, but it does the calculation every row/month. What I want it to do is to work only at a defined index. The issue is, as the panel is unbalanced, the distance between the Marches is not equally long. For example, it can be 12 months from one to another year, but it could be 10 months from the next to the following year when 2 observations are unfortunately missing. Can `roll apply` still be used? Any hints for `data table` or `dplyr` are highly appreciated.

Comment: just confirming, an ID has multiple observations on a single time point (i.e. both id=a and id=b have two rows with time=2010-03-31... and many other similar examples)?

Comment: For truly varying window there is adaptive argument in frollmean, see manual for details https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/html/froll.html

Comment: @langtang yes indeed. So there are many IDs, and all of them cover different time frames (while there is usually a large overlap). However, there are also multiple missings for each ID. So overall the panel is imbalanced.

Answer (score 3):

If this code from the question gives what you want

```
DT[,movavg := if(length(x) >= 3){ rollapply(x, 6, sum, na.rm = FALSE,align = "right",fill = NA)}else{
  rep(NA,length(x))
},by=ID]
```

then the first of these ran 2.8x faster and gave the same result and the second one using frollsum from data.table ran 4.8x faster.

```
DT[, movavg := rollsumr(x, 6, fill = NA), by = ID]
DT[, movavg := frollsum(x, 6), by = ID]
```

Comment: Nice answer, in case anyone would like to optimize and if groups are big, then dcast (ID into columns) + froll multiple columns not by group (works in parallel) + melt could eventually be faster.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about those datatable functions. A speed increase is always appreciated, I will test it. However, I was looking for something more adaptive, that means to compute the rolling sums only in March. It seems a bit of a computational waste to me to calculate them at every single time. But to achieve this, I believe, I would have to compute the intervals manually at every March. Typically intervals would range from October to March (6 months), but sometimes there are missings due to the panel structure. Maybe it is possible and even faster?

Comment: I also just realized that my code is wrong. If for example there are 5 observations missing (Nov - March), then using the past 6 months (rows) would lead to using the months: June, July, Aug, Sept, Oct - which is out of the intended 6 month window before each March (Oct - March). It is unlikely to have that many missings, but possible.